# C# How can i implement paging on Grid.Mvc with ajax (No full page reload)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, grid.mvc

I have a model that contains a List of objects that i display using `@Html.Grid(Model).` It works fine but when changing pages/sorting it reloads the entire page. How can I Implement paging so that it reloads the new page only without reloading the entire page?

Comment: kindly show what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, you can use jqgrid or you can buy the Telerik Framework, but at first look at [jqgrid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/801895/ASP-NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-and-JQGrid-Demo-wit) and how to use it in asp.mvc

Answer (score 0):

There are so many Online jquery Libraries are available 
refer these links you may get idea

http://gijgo.com/ 
http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/